# how'd I get the sum of all positively entered numbers

Tags: c++

I've been trying to come up with a method to get the sum of all positively entered numbers based on the code below

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void myFunction(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    int x;
    x = 0;
    if (num1 > 0) {
        x++;
    }
    if (num2 > 0) {
        x++;
    }
    if (num3 > 0) {
        x++;
    }
    cout << "From the entered numbers " << x << " of them are positive numbers";
}


int main() {
    
    int y1, y2, y3;
    
    cout << "Enter numbers: ";
                                                                   
    cin >> y1 >> y2 >> y3;
    
    myFunction(y1, y2, y3);                   
    
}
```

But I just can't think of anything as I am quite new to programming. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `x++` is `x = x + 1` So `x` can only ever be `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Comment: `x += num1` etc

Comment: your program **count** the positive number you want to **sum** them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mentioned in comment you are **counting** not **summing**, but as new programmer you can think about the condition where you check if the integer is positive - for example `if (num1 > 0) { // here you add sum or count depends what you want }`

so i can suggest your **myFunction** can be like :

```
void myFunction(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
int x, positive_sum;
x = 0, positive_sum = 0;
if (num1 > 0) {
    // here we deal with positive
    x++;
    positive_sum += num1;
}
if (num2 > 0) {
    x++;
    positive_sum += num2;
}
if (num3 > 0) {
    x++;
    positive_sum += num3;
}
cout << "From the entered numbers " << x << " of them are positive numbers"<<endl;
cout << "Sum of these " << x << " numbers is " << positive_sum << endl; }
```

i hope it makes it clear for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional statement to reduce your code and make it cleaner

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void myFunction(int num1, int num2, int num3) {

    int x= (num1>=0?1:0) + (num2>=0?1:0) + (num3>=0?1:0);

    cout << "From the entered numbers " << x << " of them are positive numbers";

    int sum= (num1>0?num1:0) + (num2>0?num2:0) + (num3>0?num3:0);

    cout<<sum;
}


int main() {

    int y1, y2, y3;
    
    cout << "Enter numbers: ";
                                                                   
    cin >> y1 >> y2 >> y3;
    
    myFunction(y1, y2, y3);                   
}
```